# ASP MVC Create parameters model even when any parameters wasn't provided

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, rest

I'm creating a RESTful API with ASP.Net MVC
Have problem with one GET route. I created a parameters model to handle all receiving params.

```
 public class MyParameters : BaseParameters
 {
    public string ProductCode { get; set; }
    ...
 }
```

and using this class in this way:

```
 public HttpResponseMessage Get([FromUri] MyParameters filter)
```

The problem is when i don't pass any parameters - the filter object not being initialized. It is always null.
But I need this object to be initialized anyway, because there are some default parameters, like flags, which I initialize in constructor.

```
 public MyParameters()
    {
        AuthFlag = 'Y';
    }
```

I know that it is default behaviour, but I don't want to do something like this:

```
if (filter == null)
      filter = new MyParameters();
```

Maybe Is there any configuration available to make parameters objects created anyway?

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's the null propagation operator:

```
filter = filter ?? new MyParameters();
```

or you can implement your own model binder/model binder provider.  As a starting point, you can reference [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding).